# Generate random numbers where the difference is always positive

Tags: random, kotlin

I am trying to generate some numbers, such that the difference is always positive. the user inputs the number of digits and the amount of rows they want. for example 3 digits 3 rows will produce

```
971
888
121
```

I want to make sure the difference of those is always positive. is there some kind of algorithm I can use. right now i just have my program create numbers, then subtract them and if it comes out negative, it will do it again... and again. It is very slow.

I was thinking of first generating the difference and then adding to it until the amount of desired rows is reached. But i ran into problems if i generates a very large number.

here is the code i use to generate a random number with X digits, just in case it matters

```
private fun createRandomNumber(digits: Int): Int {
        val numberArray = IntArray(digits)
        for (number in 0 until numberArray.size){
            numberArray[number] = 9
        }
        val maxnumber:Int = numberArray.joinToString("").toInt()
        numberArray[0] = 1
        for (number in 1 until numberArray.size){
            numberArray[number] = 0
        }
        val minnumber:Int = numberArray.joinToString("").toInt()
        return (minnumber..maxnumber).random()
    }
```

based on the suggestion by Jeff Bowman, I began by sorting an array with all the numbers that are generated and it speeds everything up to an acceptable amount!

Comment: Can you generate arbitrary numbers as you have, and then just sort them?

Comment: @JeffBowman actually that could work! I didn't even think of that. Will report back

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: @matt that is in kotlin (base don Java) for android.

Comment: Thanks. Added that as a tag, as you should have done.

Comment: @matt I didn't think the language mattered. I just wanted an idea of how to do it, that could fit any language i might want to do it in. I just provided my bit of code to show that i tried something. Will make sure i have a language written down next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when @forpas solution is fine, it still runs in `O(n log n)` because of the final sorting. My solution just generates the increasing intervals where to generate random numbers (for uniformity distribution), and then `map` each interval to a random number in that range, hence avoiding the need to sort the final list. Complexity is `O(n)`

I chose to use `Stream` to avoid mutation or explicit recursion, but is not mandatory.

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val count = 20L
    val digits = 5

    val min =  pow(10.0, digits.toDouble() - 1).toLong()
    val max = min*10 - 1
    val gap = (max - min)/count + 1

    val numbers =
        Stream.iterate(Pair(min, min + gap)) { (_, prev) -> Pair(prev, prev + gap) }
            .map { (start, end) -> Random.nextLong(start, end) }
            .limit(count)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) 

    numbers.forEach(::println)
}
```

**Output**

```
11298
16284
20841
26084
31960
35538
37208
45325
46970
52918
57514
59769
67689
70135
75338
78075
84561
86652
91938
99931
```

Comment: I like your was better

Answer (score 1):

I would use this function to create a random number with a certain number of digits:

```
fun createRandomNumber(digits: Int) = (10f.pow(digits - 1).toInt() until 10f.pow(digits).toInt()).shuffled().first()
```

you will need this import:

```
import kotlin.math.pow
```

And then with this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("how many numbers?: ")
    val numbers = readLine()!!.toInt()
    print("how many digits?: ")
    val digits = readLine()!!.toInt()

    val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    do {
        set.add(createRandomNumber(digits))
    } while (set.size < numbers)

    val array = set.toTypedArray().sortedArrayDescending()
    array.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

you get the user's input and create a set of random numbers. 
With `toTypedArray().sortedArrayDescending()` you get the array.